# Htaccess Rename php file into friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rename

my problem is i want to rename this 2 urls with htaccess and i have no idea

want to convert

```
mydomain.com/info.php?act=statistics
mydomain.com/info.php?act=about_us
```

into

```
mydomain.com/statistics
mydomain.com/about_us
```

I will be very grateful since i dont know anything about htaccess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /info.php?act=$1 [L]
```

This will pass /whatever to /info.php?act=whatever
The ! -f and ! -d RewriteCond checks to be sure the file doesn't exist first.

Comment: Thanks a lot chovy, this worked for me. I also have a file which is users.php?act=gallery , so /gallery redirects to /info.php?act=gallery

How do i change this in the htaccess to allow me use different php files? i dont know if you understand me. please help me

Comment: Just put this above the more general wildcard rule: `RewriteRule ^/gallery$ /users.php?act=gallery [L]`